# User Input in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am writing a matlab code which, after calculation, prints a report in pdf format. I am using actxserver for communicating with Microsoft Word. The user inputs the filename of the final report and it gets saved in a folder which is predefined.

I am using,

name = input('Please enter the filename','s');

```
WordFileName=name;
FileSpec = fullfile(pwd,WordFileName);
[ActXWord,WordHandle]=StartWord(FileSpec);

function [actx_word,word_handle]=StartWord(word_file_p)

    actx_word = actxserver('Word.Application');
    word_handle = invoke(actx_word.Documents,'Add');

end

function CloseWord(actx_word_p,word_handle_p,word_file_p)
word_handle_p.ExportAsFixedFormat(word_file_p,17);
end
```

When the user inputs : report  ,   the pdf gets generated as report.pdf

but when the filename has another characters like for example '1.2MFQ', a file gets generated with filename '1.2MFQ' and filetype '2MFQ' with no pdf extension.

Is this because of the input in matlab or during printing as pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's word doing it and not Matlab. Why not just append .pdf to the file name string in the beginning:

```
FileSpec = fullfile(pwd,[WordFileName, ".pdf"]);
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same but i felt when you input 'report' as filename it may come out as report.pdf.pdf.. but i was wrong.. it works perfectly fine... thanks Dan...